# Is there an equivalent in DrRacket to set-car! and set-cdr! in SICP?

Tags: scheme, variable-assignment, racket

Is there an equivalent in DrRacket to set-car! and set-cdr! in SICP?

Comment: set-car! and set-car! are mutators used to modify pointers in scheme. They work in MIT scheme, but not in DrRacket.

Comment: Retagged your post. If inappropriate, please change.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go through SICP with Racket, you should use [Neil's package](http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-plt/) that makes it easier -- you'd get a language with `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use [mutable pairs.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html)